# startSubActivity

Tags: android

When use startSubActivity in my android application it shows an error

> The method startSubActivity(Intent,
>   int) is undefined for the type
>   RssReader

RssReader is the classname.
I already add the activity as :-

```
<activity android:name=".ShowDescription" >
          <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you show your java code to know how you have called startSubActivity

Answer (score 5):

Try using `startActivityForResult` instead.

The function `startSubActivity` was never really released to the public (as far as I know), it was just renamed to `startActivityForResult`.

Comment: I always wonder what this method for as I see every now on then on web +1 for explaining it